# angular-moment not showing anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-moment

I have in my controller a variable with the current date formatted as `yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss`

It is being formatted correctly since I'm printing it, and it look fine:
`2016.09.01 16:13:15`

in my view, I have a span like this:

```
<span class="date" am-time-ago="notification.datetime | amParse:'YYYY.MM.DD HH:mm:ss'"></span>
```

I have correctly imported the the code files:

```
<script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>
```

however, nothing is being shown inside the the span, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an angular expression in your span so

```
<span class="date" am-time-ago="notification.datetime | amParse:'YYYY.MM.DD HH:mm:ss'">{{date|amParse:"YYYY.MM.DD HH:mm:ss"}}</span>
```